# Is there a way to receive all packets before handling then?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a application which has the following loop:

```
void receive() {
    socket.async_receive_from( asio::buffer(buffer,buffer_len),recv_endpoint,
    [&)(const ec& error, size_t recvd_len) {
        if( error ) throw error;
        new_packet(buffer,recvd_len);
        handle_received();
        receive();
    });
};
```

What happens is that my `handle_received()` function is very slow, and when it is finished, there is already a lot of packets waiting in the UDP buffer. What I wanted to achieve is receive everything that is available first, and then, invoke `handle_received()` just once.

Comment: Are you using TCP sockets? Then it's even worse, as TCP is a streaming protocol, and any receive call can give you any amount of data. What you could do is that in the handler (the lambda) you save the data in a buffer, and keep a count of the total bytes received, and when the total size passes a threshold you process the data in the stored buffer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is UDP. I did not want to follow the threshold approach because I want to minimize latency. My current issue is that I am losing packets since the code can 'receive' then fast enough.

Comment: If you're using UDP, and loose packets, you might need to implement a TCP-like protocol on top of UDP to handle resending of lost packets (and probably sequencing as well).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I mean, the machine received my packet, it is just that since I did not fetch it, it was discarded. I tolerate lost packets, it is just that I am losing more packets than necessary.

Comment: Maybe use a multi-threaded approach? One thread does the receiving, and puts messages in a queue, and another thread (or multiple threads) fetches messages from the queue and processes them. As an alternative if you use multiple processing threads might be to use one queue per thread, and add the received messages to them in a round-robbin fashion. But be careful so you don't fill the queue (or queues) faster than you can handle the messages (which brings you back to your current problem, but on a higher level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is a way to do this. However, you'll still have to pay the cost of the system call per packet.

1. Make sure your UDP socket is in non-blocking mode.

inside your receive handler:

2. push the packet you just received into a queue.
3. loop as long as the *non-async* version of `receive_from()` does not return the `asio::error::would_block` error.
4. each turn through the loop, queue up the packet you just received.
5. after the loop, run your handler function on the whole queue.

This technique is quite useful for TCP sockets as well, since it lowers the latency of picking up the next packet/buffer.

If `receive_from()` returns another error, you may want to break the loop as well, and probably handle the error somehow.

One way to make your function a bit more uniform is to issue the `async_receive_from()` with boost::asio::null_buffers`. This will call your handler when the socket becomes readable, without also handing you the packet. That way, all of your packets are read in your loop.